# Incorrect Breadcrumbs in Blogger

Tags: xml, blogger, breadcrumbs

My Breadcrumbs Appear Incorrectly on Other Blog Pages

Home Page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EueP.jpg

Others Pages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKsoA.jpg

The code for it in my template is this:

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<span class='post-tag'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:messages.home/></a> &#8594;
  </b:if>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
    <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>&#8594;</b:if>
  </b:loop>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
   <span><data:post.title/></span> 
  </b:if>
</span>
```

How to solve?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not proper here to add [SOLVED] to your title. You've told everyone it was solved by marking the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target item pages only `data:blog.pageType == "item"`

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<span class='post-tag'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:messages.home/></a> &#8594;
  </b:if>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a>
    <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>&#8594;</b:if>
  </b:loop>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
   <span><data:post.title/></span> 
  </b:if>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much